# How can I reformat date and time?

Tags: java, android, android-date

How can I convert 24 hours time format into 12 hours format? I know this question has been asked many times, but my problem is different. My current time is:

> Tue Nov 07 18:44:47 GMT+05:00 2017

I just want 6:44 pm from my date time. I tried this:

```
private void convertTime(String time)
{
    try {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
        final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
        System.out.println(dateObj);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a").format(dateObj));
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your problem different? In what way does your attempt fail? Please quote any error messages and any stacktrace verbatim.

Comment: @Ole When I was posting this question I was not aware about my problem and I think that it is different from the problem that i asked earlier but after getting suitable answer i got to know that this is not different than the questions which have been asked earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation:

> "h:mm a":     12:08 PM

So the format you need for:

> I just want **6:44 pm** from my date time

is:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = sdf1.parse(time);
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
String newDateString = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: but i have this time in string "Tue Nov 07 18:44:47 GMT+05:00 2017" and I need only hours and minutes with 12 hours format

Comment: Ok updated my answer, `time` is the `String time` parameter of your `convertTime` method

Answer (score 3):

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
```

Using `hh` will give you 12 hours format and `HH` 24 hour format. More details on [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**Edit:**

Your initial format must be the following in order to parse your date string to a `Date` object:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
```

After that you can format time to your needs.

Comment: but i have this time Tue Nov 07 18:44:47 GMT+05:00 2017 and i need only hours and minutes with 12 hours format

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println(dateObj);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a").format(dateObj));
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```